# How do I combine lines in a text file in a specific order?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to transform the text in a file according the following rule: for each line, if the line does not begin with "https", add that word to the beginning of subsequent lines until you hit another line with a non-https word.

For example, given this file:

```
Fruit
https://www.apple.com//
https://www.banana.com//
Vegetable
https://www.cucumber.com//
https://www.lettuce.com//
```

I want

```
Fruit-https://www.apple.com//
Fruit-https://www.banana.com//
Vegetable-https://www.cucumber.com//
Vegetable-https://www.lettuce.com//
```

Here is my attempt:

```
one = open("links.txt", "r")
for two in one.readlines():

    if "https" not in two:
        sitex = two
        
    else:
        print (sitex + "-" +two)
```

Here is the output of that program, using the above sample input file:

```
Fruit
-https://www.apple.com//

Fruit
-https://www.banana.com//       

Vegetable
-https://www.cucumber.com//     

Vegetable
-https://www.lettuce.com//
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: First of all, I strongly recommend using variable names that indicate what they are or what they do - they have some sort of meaning. Beyond that, how can you keep track of lines that start with `"https"` until getting to a line that doesn't, then going back and adding it to a previous line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to strip the trailing newline from the line if it doesn't contain `'https'`:

```py
sitex = two
```

should be

```py
sitex = two.rstrip()
```

---

You need to do something similar for the `else` block as well, as [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) points out:

```py
print (sitex + "-" +two)
```

should be

```py
print (sitex + "-" + two.rstrip())
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. This worked but I'm still getting an empty line between items. In other words, I'm getting 8 lines instead of the desired 4. How would I fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: @firechad12: Add the same `.rstrip()` to `two` when you `print`, or skip `print`, and do `sys.stdout.write(sitex + "-" + two)` (or more cleanly, with f-strings, `sys.stdout.write(f"{sitex}-{two}")`), or keep using `print` and leave `two` unstripped, but also pass it `end=''` to stop it from automatically adding its own newline.

Answer (score 2):

To fix that we need to implement `rstrip()` method to sitex to remove the new line character at the end of the string. (credit to [BrokenBenchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71961653/11903620))

second, the print command by default newlines everytime it's called, so we must add the `end=""` parameter to fix this.

So your code should look like this

```py
one = open("links.txt", "r")
for two in one.readlines():
    if "https" not in two:
        sitex = two.rstrip()
    else:
        print (sitex + "-" +two,end="")
one.close()
```

Also always close the file when you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Lines in your file end on `"\n"` - the newline character.

You can remove whitespaces (includes `"\n"`) from a string using `strip()` (both ends) or `rstrip()` / `lstrip()` (remove at one end).

`print()` adds a `"\n"` at its end by default, you can omit this using

```
print("something", end=" ")
print("more)   # ==> 'something more' in one line
```

Fix for your code:

```
# use a context handler for better file handling
with open("data.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""Fruit
https://www.apple.com//
https://www.banana.com//
Vegetable
https://www.cucumber.com//
https://www.lettuce.com//
""")


with open("data.txt") as f:
    what = ""
    # iterate file line by line instead of reading all at once
    for line in f:
        # remove whitespace from current line, including \n
        # front AND back - you could use rstring here as well
        line = line.strip() 
        # only do something for non-empty lines (your file does not
        # contain empty lines, but the last line may be empty
        if line:
            # easier to understand condition without negation
            if line.startswith("http"):
                # printing adds a \n at the end
                print(f"{what}-{line}") # line & what are stripped
            else:
                what = line
```

Output:

```
Fruit-https://www.apple.com//
Fruit-https://www.banana.com//
Vegetable-https://www.cucumber.com//
Vegetable-https://www.lettuce.com//
```

See:

- [str.lstrip(*[chars]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip)
- [str.rstrip(*[chars]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)
- [str.strip(*[chars]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

*[chars]* are optional - if not given, whitespaces are removed.